# Kafka Consumer metrics gone upon upgrade from Spring Boot 2.2.2 to 2.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator

## Problem:

We upgraded our Spring Boot version from 2.2.2 to 2.3.0, and all of the `kafka_consumer_*` metrics that were seen in the Prometheus endpoint in 2.2.2 are not visible in 2.3.0.

For example, all of the below are missing:

- `kafka_consumer_records_consumed_total_records_total`
- `kafka_consumer_records_lag_records`
- `kafka_consumer_fetch_latency_max_seconds`
- `kafka_consumer_bytes_consumed_total_bytes_total`

Not sure if we're missing some kind of configuration or something buried in the docs...

## What has been tried:

- Combed the Spring Boot 2.3.0 release notes, updated micrometer documentation, and updated spring-kafka documentation for why this might be happening
- Googled to what feels like the ends of the Earth
- Tried upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.7 and the kafka metrics are still there, only upgrading to 2.3.0 seems to cause the issue
- Removed any non-needed dependency/customization that was in our code for the project, and bare bones just connected to a kafka container on the localhost, and the metrics still don't appear

## Relevant code/details:

- We're using Red Hat AMQ Streams for our kafka broker (kafka version 2.1.1)
- The only thing we've changed in our environment is the Spring Boot version (and dependencies that are automatically pulled in/updated) to recreate this issue

Below is our `build.gradle.kts` before the change:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
}

group = "ourGroup"
version = "0.0.1"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "Hoxton.RELEASE"

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Now, if we just update our `build.gradle.kts` with a new spring boot version like in the below line our kafka metrics disappear:

```
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.0.RELEASE"
```

Below are screenshots of the prometheus metrics we were seeing before and after the change:

[Before 2.3.0 upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDLi1.png)

[After 2.3.0 upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wbxd.png)

Thanks in advance for the help! Let me know if you need any other details!

Comment: I am using `spring-kafka` and just tested @AlanYeung's issue. I can confirm that in Spring Boot `2.3.0.RELEASE`, the `kafka_consumer_*` metrics are gone in `/actuator/prometheus`. I can still see them in `2.2.7.RELEASE`.

Comment: Kafka meters were migrated from scraping JMX MBeans to using native metrics in Boot 2.0. See [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/888a81beba23728078337ad91c27ca4abbcb189e#diff-2f3136f1958043f3d7c37de45bf062fa) and [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d16074d8fdc457107177bca026635e4575fe0c08#diff-2f3136f1958043f3d7c37de45bf062fa). The last one uses [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/4c313955a67946bc9bf5c9fec40b26d700f7ffb2). I'll see if I can figure out what's broken tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome @GaryRussell, thanks a lot for the pointers! I have the `kafka_consumer_*` metrics back in `2.3.0.RELEASE`. Cheers!

Comment: Correction `>in Boot 2.0` should be in Boot 2.3.

Comment: I'd like to see more new contributors put this much effort into their first question. Nice job, Alan!

Comment: @GaryRussell @jumping_monkey I am having the same problem, and despite reading all this I am really not clear what the solution is. I am not using `spring-kafka` to generate my consumers, although I did try adding that dependency. It did not help. With SpringBoot 2.2.13 worked without spring-kafka. All later version of SpringBoot fail even with spring-kafka dependency.

Comment: Boot changed from scraping JMX MBeans to using the native `KafkaClientMetrics` provided by Micrometer. If you are creating Consumers yourself you will have to register your own metrics with the meter registry - this is how spring-kafka does it... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/4f44ad4e968281606382d2a3c2227a42ed6a327e/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/MicrometerConsumerListener.java#L73-L74

Comment: Hey, for me Kafka producer metrics is not coming even in SpringBoot 2.2.6.  I raise a question plz help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899965/how-to-expose-kafka-producer-metrics-to-prometheus-with-spring-boot-2-2-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for normal spring-kafka consumers

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So62292889Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62292889Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so62292889", topics = "so62292889")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so62292889").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return args -> {
            registry.getMeters().forEach(meter -> System.out.println(meter.getId()));
        };
    }

}
```

```
MeterId{name='kafka.consumer.outgoing.byte.total'...
```

I see you are using spring-cloud-stream. The problem is that this project creates its own producer/consumer factories and doesn't add the Micrometer listeners.

I [opened an issue against the binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/914).

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @jumping_monkey, I have a `spring-kafka` app using Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE, and the `kafka_consumer_*` metrics were not showing up in `/actuator/prometheus`. They *did* show up when I downgraded to Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE.

It has been determined that an issue exists for apps using `spring-cloud-stream`, and there is a plan to fix that. My app does not use `spring-cloud-stream`, however; it uses `spring-kafka`.

The solution was to follow the guidance on the [spring-kafka reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer-native) to add a `MicrometerConsumerListener` to the consumer factory. After doing this, metrics show up as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please be sure not to post an answer until you've actually found a solution; the answers section shouldn't be used to reiterate that you're facing the same problem. Since you edited your answer to include a solution, I've reworded it to remove your initial follow-up questions, and lead directly into your solution.

Comment: Jeremy - thanks for the feedback. My original preference was to add a comment above, but was blocked from adding a comment because I'm a new user.  Hence, I resorted to posting a question within an answer.  I thought it best to take this approach rather than create an entirely new question/thread for the same issue - which at first I truly did not have an answer to -- after doing a fair amount of investigation.  Thanks again!

Comment: @BrentBishop Boot 2.3 will automatically add the listeners as long as the actuator starter is present - see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d16074d8fdc457107177bca026635e4575fe0c08 - I just tested it and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @GaryRussell: Thank you for testing.  Is your code using the auto-configured ConsumerFactory? My app does have actuator starter present.  Since I need to dynamically assign bootstrap servers, I have custom code to create the consumerFactory.  
I debugged through the Spring code in the commit that you shared - and observed that code to add listeners does not run, creating the need to add them in app code.
Do I have this correct?

Comment: If so, this is the point that created a little confusion for me.  With pre Boot 2.3.0 we just needed to add dependencies and metrics were available.  To continue getting metrics with 2.3.0, code is needed to add a listener.  In the end, if this is the way it is - it is a minor and reasonable change.  I didn't pickup on it when reading through the doc.

Comment: Yes; Boot will only run customizers against its auto configured factories. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/f47e06c4efbdc5a3f31684117309a62b29b2e882/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.java#L82-L90 The issue came about because Micrometer deprecated its JMX MBwan scraping mechanism for metrics. So we added the listener mechanism to spring-kafka and the Boot logic to add the listeners to its auto-configured factories, but Boot can't (and shouldn't) interfere with user-defined beans.